# Compiling React with Babel CLI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to React and trying to learn. I am trying to compile a JSX simple file manually using babel CLI. I am using the following command.

> npx babel src/App.js --out-file static/App.js

However it kind of gets stuck, and does not return.

Following are the contents of App.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: `npx -p babel-cli babel` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [transform-react-jsx plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/#usage-via-cli)

Working example :

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
npx babel App.js --out-file dist/App.js --plugins=@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Which produces :

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'h1',
  null,
  'Hello, world!'
), document.getElementById('example'));
```

Comment: I'll add that you may also set up the `plugins` & `presets` directly in your `package.json` file or a dedicated `.babelrc` file, for easier management (instead of piping it to the cli command as text)

Comment: Also note that you may use `@babel/preset-react` (*preset*) instead of `transform-react-jsx plugin`